# Can I predict future years if my model includes past years as a contrast variable?

Tags: prediction, contrasts

I've fitted a model based on data from 2002 to 2013, treating year as a contrast variable. Year is one of several predictors.

I would like to test it by asking it to predict() with newdata = data2014 and then comparing fitted with actual values. But it points out "2014 not in original fit." Oops. Is there a way around this, or is my model limited to explaining the past with no ability to predict the future?

Comment: Using year as a contrast variable is common when your goal is to find the effect of the other variables without taking into account the "yearly" effect. When doing such an approach, you need to predict this effect after. E.g. if you did a GLM, you need to find the coefficient for 2014. You may rely on your past observations (is there a link between a coefficient and the one of the previous year ? Does the coefficient have a certain shape ?). Once done you can force your data to be like "2013", and apply the "estimation" for 2014. It's not a theoretical point of view, just a heuristic.

Comment: If time is the only variable in the model and there appears to be no serial correlation in the data, the best predictor is the current sample mean. Although this is not as dependent on the passed data as you might like, it does allow a prediction of the next years value based on the passed.

Comment: Hmm, thank you Arault, interesting, I need to consider how to identify analogous years, which is kind of what the whole thing is about, identifying patterns that lead to a certain outcome. Years vary quite a bit. ... I also re-ran the model without year and it still looks pretty good, so maybe simpler is better in this case.

Comment: There are other covariates in this case, though. This is a limitation of not treating year as fixed rather than a random effect that I haven't figured out how to get past yet. One idea: make a prediction for each year and average them. So for a particular set of covariates you make 11 copies of the prediction with a different level of year and then average those predictions.

Comment: @khelmsmith the trouble with leaving out year is that it is there to account for the fact that there are multiple observations within a year.

Comment: @atiretoo Even if for model w/o year, residuals, R-square, significance of most coefficients, etc. were about the same, and AIC was a lot lower?

Comment: R squared, significance and a lot of other indicators actually rely on theory that might be not needed for some models. Could you provide more information about your problem ? How do you want to solve it ? Do you know that if your problem is about measuring something across time period and you want to use GLM, GEE are a good option ?

Comment: @Arault, I am using gam() in mgcv to predict disease incidence, which is by year and district. Variables include measures of temperature, precipitation, previous exposure and standing water.

Comment: Well, I have no prior knowledge for your specific case. In your case (and it would be exactly the same thing for GLM) I would study the evolution of the year effect. your approach of using climate variabel + geographical variables is good, and I think the time effect should be something related to previous year. Could you provide us the evolution of the year coefficient ? Considering this is something medical, time series can be helpful to understand this very "yearly" effect.